# Ads script (*.gs) is missing apps script getRange(int, int, int, int) method?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

When I run an ads-script to call the `app-script::spreadsheet` [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), I get the following error:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
var rangeValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

==> Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number)
```

How can it be? Only a subset of the app-script sheet api is available from ads-script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the variable `sheet` is an object/instance of the **spreadsheet** class. However, `getRange` is a method of the **sheet** object and **can't** be applied to the `sheet` variable.

You need to define a **sheet** object first. This can be done in many ways, one of them is to define it by using the name of the `sheet`. Here is the **spreadsheet** object:

`var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);`

Then you can define the **sheet** object:

`var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");`

And now you can get the values of a range :

`var rangeValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

Adjust `Sheet1` to the sheet of your choice. Make sure that a sheet with that name exists.